# How to use wildcard string as directory name in PowerShell's Add-CMComplianceSettingDirectory?

Tags: powershell, sccm

I try to invoke Add-CMComplianceSettingDirectory cmdlet from ConfigurationManager.psd1 module.

`$ConfigurationItem | Add-CMComplianceSettingDirectory -Name "CV" -DirectoryName "*DDD" -Path "c:\" -NoRule -DisableWildcardHandling`

But I just have the System.Management.Automation.ValidationMetadataException: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'DirectoryName'.

I assume it's just trying to process the wildcard character, but the DirectoryName parameter doesn't allow the wildcard. And I have no idea how to write directory name with wildcard to the string.

Comment: You could try by removing switch `-DisableWildcardHandling` and instead appending switch `-ForceWildcardHandling`. However, Microsoft says this may lead to unexpected behavior (not recommended)..

Comment: Unfortunately this leads to the same result.

Comment: But then... why would you need a wildcard in the directoryname anyway??

Comment: I just want to add a wildcard directory name so that sccm can find the program folder regardless of the program version. For example MyProgram*. But PowerShell thinks this should be handled as method input, not just written to sccm.